# prepare for segue...with pointers?

Tags: arrays, swift, pointers, parse-platform

```
var routes:[PFObject] = [PFObject]()

func getRoutes() {

let query = PFQuery(className: "PoolRoute")
query.includeKey("selectedCustomer")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

  if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

    self.routes = objects
    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

these objects have a column named "selectedCustomer" that is full of pointer objects.....I would like to segue to another tableview controller and display the pointer objects from the selected cell...

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

  if segue == "toRoutesDetailVC" {

    let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! PoolRouteDetailVC
    if let indexPath = self.tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow {

  nav.currentObject = (self.routes[indexPath.row]["selectedCustomer"] as [PFObject])
```

//  '() -> NSIndexPath?' does not have a member named 'row'
//i guess its not the right syntax...not exactly sure how to write the code to get it to send to the array to the detailViewController. thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Maybe its because I don't know swift, but your code looks fine.  "Not the right syntax" implies a compiler error/warning.  Which line, what's the error/warning?  It is worth noting that the variable name and the column name are a sign of existing confusion or confusion to come later:  the vc variable name is singular "currentObject", but it takes an array?  The column name in parse is singular "selectedCustomer" but its an array?  And are those customers in the array?  "poolAccounts" seems like a better name.

Comment: '() -> NSIndexPath?' does not have a member named 'row' is the error it gives me. ill update my code so its not confusing with singulars and plurals.